# Deploying ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, deployment

i'm trying to deploy asp.net application, i transfered all the files into server's root directory by ftp.

but i got this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Runtime Error 
>   Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

Blockquote

I added  line but the error is still the same..;/

locally everything works fine.
what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your own server?  In other words, do you have direct access to IIS on this server?  Maybe you already did this, but in case you didn't: You need to create an application for the site in IIS.  The easiest way to do this is to right-click on your website (Default Website if you only have one) in IIS and choose "Add Virtual Directory..."